PHP socket_bind to remote address
I'm trying to do the php socket_bind to the fingerprint machine(192.168.18.xxx) which is in the same network as my machine(192.168.18.yyy). I've successfully do the socket_bind for my machine ip but couldn't do it for the fingerprint machine. Any way which I can achieve this from php?
My Code is,
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, 192.168.18.xxx, 7788);
socket_listen($socket, 32);


"socket_bind to remote address" That makes no sense. socket_bind() must be called with a local address.

For what purpose?

To get some data from Fingerprint Machine. I can ping from my local machine since it's in the same network. But cannot do it from remote address.

If you want to get data from another machine, you connect to it. It should be running a server that returns the data.

bind and listen are for creating a server that waits for clients to connect to it.
